# Derivative of solution w.r.t initial conditions?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, education, computational-mathematics

Consider an autonomous system ($y$ is a vector)

$\dfrac{dy}{dt}=f(y)$ , $y(0)=x$

having the solution

$y=y(t,x)$

How am I suppose to compute the derivative

$\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}$

at ($x_i,T_i)$ (the guessed initial conditions and guessed period) when I DON'T know the explicit function $y=y(t,x)$. Because the solution of the original ODE is purely numerical. That ODE simply cannot be solved analytically, I only have the numbers. I'm trying to use that to correct the set of guessed initial conditions I found. That derivative I'm trying to get is part of the 1st-order Taylor expansion.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: My guess is that you know $y(x_i,T_j)$ and $y(x_{i+1},T_j)$. Then the derivative is $(y(x_{i+1},T_j)-y(x_i,T_j))/(x_{i+1}-x_i)$

Comment: If you know what $f'$ is, then by writing $u = \partial y/\partial x$ we find that $$\frac{d}{dt}(y, u) = (f(y), f'(y)\cdot u)$$ with $(y(0), u(0)) = (x, 1)$. So I guess you may run a numerical computation solving this system of equations.

Comment: My system is autonomous, so $f'=0$, I suppose? Is it $y'=f$ you're going with? I only know the numerical solution to the original ODEs, a 'single' set of numbers $(x_i,T_i)$ which is guessed, don't even know other initial conditions like $x_{i+1}$ or $x_{i-1}$. 



What I was told is $\partial y/\partial x$ at the guessed initial condition $(x_i,T_i)$ is the 'monodromy matrix'. The thing is I know of no way to compute such matrix.